# How to perform partial text search with solr with nested documents?

Tags: solr

I am using **apache solr** for **text search**. I have **nested document structure**. This is **one.json** file :

```
{
"id": "1",
"info": {
       "first_name": "John",
       "last_name": "Doe",
       "gender": "male"
        }
}
```

I have created a **solr core** named "**demo**" using following command:

```
solr create -c demo
```

Then, I posted above record for indexing using the following command:

```
bin/post -c demo docs2/   //docs2 has the one.json file
```

Solr indexed and flattened the above document's nested structure , I guess for better indexing in following form:

```
{
    "id":["1"],
    "info.first_name":["John"],
    "info.last_name":["Doe"],
    "personal.gender":["male"]
}
```

Now, when I make the search query with text "John":

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/demo/select?indent=on&q=John&wt=json
```

It works and gives the desired result.

But, when I try to make the partial search with text "Joh":

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/demo/select?indent=on&q=Joh&wt=json
```

It does not work and returns empty.

How do I make this type of search ? Am I missing some thing for indexing to make partial text search?

Comment: use wildcard * search `http://localhost:8983/solr/demo/select?indent=on&q=Joh*&wt=json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

search for Joh* and this should work